# Pass a variable argument list

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiactionsheet, objective-c-blocks

I would like to create a subclass of `UIActionSheet` that uses blocks instead of delegation. So I created the following class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

// Public Interface
typedef void (^FJActionSheetCompletion)(int buttonIndex);

@interface FJActionSheet : UIActionSheet

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
    completionBlock:(FJActionSheetCompletion)completionBlock
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ... NS_REQUIRES_NIL_TERMINATION;

@end

// Private Interface
@interface FJActionSheet() <UIActionSheetDelegate>
{
    FJActionSheetCompletion _completionBlock;
}
@end

// Implementation
@implementation FJActionSheet

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)title 
    completionBlock:(FJActionSheetCompletion)completionBlock
  cancelButtonTitle:(NSString *)cancelButtonTitle 
destructiveButtonTitle:(NSString *)destructiveButtonTitle 
  otherButtonTitles:(NSString *)otherButtonTitles, ...
{
    self = [super initWithTitle:title
                       delegate:self
              cancelButtonTitle:cancelButtonTitle
         destructiveButtonTitle:destructiveButtonTitle
              otherButtonTitles:otherButtonTitles];

    if (self)
    {
        _completionBlock = [completionBlock copy];
    }

    return self;
}

- (void)actionSheet:(UIActionSheet *)actionSheet didDismissWithButtonIndex:(NSInteger)buttonIndex
{
    _completionBlock(buttonIndex);
}

@end
```

This works except for one problem: I can not pass multiple strings for `otherButtonTitles`. If I do it as above, I (obviously) get a "Missing sentinel in method dispatch".

My question is: How can I pass the `otherButtonTitles` argument to the initializer of `UIActionSheet`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

see this [great blog post](http://cocoawithlove.com/2009/05/variable-argument-lists-in-cocoa.html) about variadic methods. Mainly how to access the variable arguments by using

```
va_list args;
va_start(args, firstArg);
va_arg(args, NSString*)
```

Comment: Do I not see it or did you forget to include a link?

Comment: Sorry. It was a long night yesterday :)

Comment: I see. So I can access all the strings and then add the additional buttons using `-addButtonWithTitle:`. There is no direct way then?

Comment: I guess there isn't an direct way, as the initializer doesn't offer a `arguments` parameter.